# Getting started with robotics

Tags: robotics

My brother is a senior in High School. When he visited our college. I've took him to a robotics event (inter college robotics competition). He got to see various bots designed by college students and got mesmerised. Now he too wants to design bots like that.

I told him programming is necessary. He already knows little bit and I'm helping him in becoming proficient. But I've no clue regarding this field.

Can any one kindly suggest a path & tiny projects to improve his interest.

Comment: If you're into building robots, don't forget to commit to the [Robotics Proposal](http://http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if there's a FIRST team at his high school. They're a great place to start learning about robotics and he'll get to actually make stuff. If not, something like a [Lego NXT kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001USHRYI) or Vex kit would be a good place to start. They've both got pretty easy methods of programming, and since they have pieces you put together, you don't need to worry about machining your own parts. That way he can concentrate on getting something actually working and driving around instead of designing electronics, fixing tough programming bugs, buying stock and milling parts.

Comment: +1. Thank you. Can you add this url to your answer? Lego NXT kit: http://www.amazon.com/LEGO-4544091-Mindstorms-NXT-2-0/dp/B001USHRYI/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top and When I got confused to go with NXT or Vex kit. This http://www.vexforum.com/showthread.php?t=6551 says, NXT is for beginners & Vex is for advanced users because Vex is more flexible than NXT.

Comment: I'd agree that Vex is probably a bit more advanced. NXT is also easier to program. If he already has some Legos, then NXT is probably a better choice. After he gets comfortable making stuff with NXT, then the next step is Vex or maybe an Arduino kit like Throwback1986 mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The NXT is great - my 10 year-old son loves it.  If the Lego systems are too basic, I recommend the [Arduino](http://www.robotshop.com/dfrobotshop-rover-tracked-robot-basic-kit.html) robot series.

Answer (score 0):

Do check out www.Letsmakerobots.com  and Also my site (http://www.neurogoody.com/p/robotics.html) which deals providing beginners in robotics with some awesome posts and video tutorials (More stuff to come in 2 weeks!)

Hope you and your bro make a robot very soon! :) 
Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

Arduino is a wonderful hardware and software system to learn robotics. I would like to suggest to start with this one. FYI, I am CTO of a robotics company.